# Order queryset by date in descending order, but for elements which dates are less that now() order in ascending?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a queryset that i want to kind of split in two parts. Part one would contain objects with future dates and part two - past dates. The thing is: i need to sort two part with different order. One - descending, two - ascending.

I need the output to be Queryset, not list, since I want to use filters and pagination on them.

Is it possible?

Comment: use filter on queryset and orderby. queryset apply pagination

Comment: @HemanthSP Makes sense, but I managed to solve it myself. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve that myself:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Sum
from django.db.models import When, Case

def get_queryset(self):
    return Course.objects.filter(status=1, type_course=2).annotate(
        past_date=Case(
            When(date__lt=date.today(), then=0),
            When(date__gte=date.today(), then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )).order_by('-past_date', 'date')
```